# is it possible to have VS2010 localhost repsond to LAN requests when debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am trying to test some new code between my iOS app and my new server code.  It would greatly simplify things if I could submit requests to my local testing server while I am debugging so I can fix things quickly on the fly.

Is this possible?

Comment: personally, I'd mock away the calls to the server.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I can replicate what is coming from the mobile app and just test that locally but it would be nice to see the entire transaction happen

Comment: yeah, but you add a dependency to a running server. I'd say that you have tests that confirm that the info that the server sends is OK and then tests that the client handles that correctly. No dependencies, all is tested.

Comment: Have you tried using IIS configured with your application as Virtual App? Instead of this you can use IIS Express (VS Plugin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible by design - which is a good thing.

However, if you are hell bent on doing this, you can do so by setting up a proxy on the development machine that will redirect the traffic to your localhost as required.

The full details steps are described here - http://encosia.com/using-an-iphone-with-the-visual-studio-development-server/.

Summary

1. Get Fiddler/Install Fiddler on the development machine - [http://www.fiddler2.com](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp)
2. Determine the fiddler port and ensure it is configured to accept connections.
3. Determine your ip address.
4. On the iphone configure the proxy with the info from steps 2/3. (Connections > Proxy > Manual).
5. You may need to a period(.) to the address eg, `http://localhost.:4543/website` to make it work.